# SerialVersionUID JavaDoc?

Tags: java, documentation, javadoc, serialversionuid

When adding documentation to my Java program, I realize that most classes require a `serialVersionUID` constant property to be declared. How exactly should I document this property? And do I document it differently if I used a default vs. generated serial version UID?

```
/**
 * What goes here? "A unique serial version identifier"
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -8922096951749901688L;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the `serialVersionUID` comment you provided seems right **but unnecessary**.

The `serialVersionUID` is required as part of a  `Serializable` object (*not all java classes*) and is used during the serialization / deserialization of this objects.

As a general rule. **ALWAYS CHECK THE [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)**
*in this case, `Serializable` API, at the bottom!!*

> The serialization runtime associates with each serializable class a version number, called a serialVersionUID, which is used during deserialization to verify that the sender and receiver of a serialized object have loaded classes for that object that are compatible with respect to serialization. If the receiver has loaded a class for the object that has a different serialVersionUID than that of the corresponding sender's class, then deserialization will result in an InvalidClassException. A serializable class can declare its own serialVersionUID explicitly by declaring a field named "serialVersionUID" that must be static, final, and of type long:
>
> ```
> ANY-ACCESS-MODIFIER static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;
> ```

---

> So you're saying that it should actually not be documented whatsoever because there is javadoc for it already? When I omit the javadoc and mouseover it, it does not show anything `:/`

It's part of `Serializable` interface, so IMHO is not necessary... anyway, you can use your own comment + `@see` annotation. Something like this (not sure if will work, cannot create javadoc now...)

```
/**
 * A unique serial version identifier
 * @see Serializable#serialVersionUID
 */
```

Comment: So you're saying that it should actually not be documented whatsoever because there is javadoc for it already? When I omit the javadoc and mouseover it, it does not show anything :/

Comment: @NoodleofDeath Most Java developers will know what it is for. Probably the most helpful and simplest documentation you can give is to link to the [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) javadocs and leave it. Of course you're free to add more information if you want.

Comment: @NoodleofDeath check my update... 4castle is right... almost people will know what is already....

Comment: Made a minor modification to your java doc `Serializable#serialVersionUID`.

Comment: The `@see Serializable#serialVersionUID` makes doclint choke. The reason is simple: there is no field called `serialVersionUID` in the `Serializable` interface. I think that a simple `@see Serializable` would do it. CC @NoodleOfDeath